# Password escapes in SQL Azure connection string

Tags: entity-framework-core, passwords, ado.net, azure-sql-database, connection-string

I had the bright idea of generating a secure password using KeePass password manager and give it to my DBA.

Now I constructed my Azure SQL connection string as follows

```
Server=tcp:something.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=SomeDbName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=someuser;Password=[read later];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

The password contains **at least** the following characters, along with upper/lowercase/digits

```
/"|&@]<#
```

Error is: `ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 151.`

At index 151 I can see the semicolon after the username (which I named `someuser` in the redacted example but only contains lowercase and a digit). VS Code points column 151 right before the `;Password=` sequence

Questions:

- Does my SQL Azure password contain illegal characters?
- Which ones need to be escaped?
- How do I escape them?

[Edit]: a note about the double quotes, which must be always escaped in C# Strings. I buried the connection string under Azure App configuration tab. It means that the double quote is unlikely to be re-escaped. I believe EF Core currently reads `double-quote` correctly

Comment: I have fixed the problem by regenerating a password without `double-quote` but I am still curious about the escaping for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually escaping is specified here: [connection-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings)

Simple test shows that for your password, it is enough to add single quotes:

```cs
var csBuilder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
csBuilder.Password = "/\"|&@]<#";

var cs = csBuilder.ConnectionString;
Console.WriteLine(cs);
```

```
Password='/"|&@]<#'
```